# MS Access ? about data types

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to copy and paste baseball stats into Access. I am working with numbers as the data type but occasionally a player will have what they call inf (stands for infinity).  Obviously inf is text so how do I type it in when its the only cell in under that field that isn't a number. I cant use the short text or long text option because then I can't format how I want the numbers to look (for instance #.##). Is there a way to specify an exception to the rule for the data type?

Comment: No. Use a number that could be interpreted as infinite such as 9999999 and then handle it in expressions to format. Or leave the field Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question.  You have stated that you have fields that are "numbers as the data type".

**Number fields only take numbers**.  That is a basic premise that Access will always enforce.

You then state that you want to format the word "inf" representing "infinity" into a number field.

It seems that you have two options:

1. translate "inf" into a special number to be stored in the field.  The special number could be a very large number, e.g. 1,000,000.  Or, the special number could be -1 (a number that no one would ever have for a statistic.  You would need to translate the "inf" entry into one of these during data import or when preparing the data prior to import.
2. You could use text fields rather than number fields and then translate the fields to numbers when you want to perform operations.  This seems like a poor solution as Access would require a lot of coding to handle this type of solution.  However, it could be done.

Comment: Thanks that seems to makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Unless you see another solution, it would be appropriate to accept the answer.  Thank you, and good luck!